# Tuning kit and timing belt

Tags: audi, timing-belt, tuning

I have an AUDI Berliner A4, 130 HP, 1.9 TDI, B6, 2002. I bought [this tuning kit](https://www.etsy.com/fr/listing/1213946910/puce-tuner-haute-performance-stage-20?campaign_label=proteus_transaction_buyer_notification_boe_convo_url_treatment&utm_source=transactional&utm_campaign=proteus_transaction_buyer_notification_boe_convo_url_treatment_010170_419265317394_0_0&utm_medium=email&utm_content=&email_sent=1659430857&euid=URmbkg_EWi-8LmNp67y6szXFO5mz&eaid=638923179726&x_eaid=5813ea38e4), and I'm wondering if I should change the timing belt immediately even though it has marched only for 50.000 km, and if I should change to a specific timing belt that can take the chipped new engine?

Are there other things I should consider with the "new engine"? PS: It's an AVF engine.

Thanks

Comment: tdiclub.com has TDI experts and forums for all generations of TDIs. You'll want to give the part number of the existing timing belt or say if it's the original from 2002.

Comment: So I just ask there? The timing belt is new, and typical GATES  belt.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @vqngs Yes, that's what I'm suggesting: ask at tdiclub.com. You will almost certainly find people there who have done what you are planning to do. Search their forum specific to your vehicle first, of course. Your question may already have been answered.

Comment: Wow, that item is complete garbage.  You can't do appreciable tunes from the OBD port.  Anyway no product could possibly work on ALL Ford cars in a huge range of years (which happens to *exactly* match the years OBDII ports exist). It does nothing but scam people who want more power but aren't willing to turn a wrench. *But of course, you don't know this, and hold out high hopes*.  Send it back mercilessly - these scammers need to suffer.  *But of course when it does nothing, you won't bother.*

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, change or don't change the timing belt. It really won't matter. If the belt only has 50kkm on it, that is about 1/2 way through its life (life expectancy for most vehicles is 60k miles or 100kkm). Although, you can't go wrong with a new timing belt. As long as whomever is doing the change knows what they are doing, it's fairly straight forward and you won't harm anything by putting a new one on. Gates make good products, so no worries there. To my knowledge, there aren't any "performance" specific timing belts (there are performance cogs which allow you to change the specific timing of the cam).

**NOTE:** As far as what you're buying. I see they are promising a "Max" increase of torque and power. It is my experience with such things, you won't get what they promise. Not even close. These are pretty much a "come-on", meaning, they aren't worth the money you are paying for shipping. I know the Mighty Car Mods did some testing with something similar, tearing it apart to show there's nothing really there. Tuning a car involves actually changing fuel/timing/boost maps inside of the ECU. This CANNOT be accomplished by plugging something like this into the OBDII port. It requires software and know how, neither of which is provided via the plug in dongle.  I'm pretty sure if you went on YouTube and searched for this specific product, you might find "honest" reviews.

Comment: Great , thanks for this answer. It is certainly enlightening. I will check on the reputation of these guys and see. Regarding the timing belt, I was sure that if one increases the effect on an engine to say double, there could be much more strain on the timing belt, particularly if accelerating uphill. So that was my concern.

Comment: @vqngs A timing belt experiences greater strain when the engine is cold, when the RPM is high and when the RPM changes quickly. Aside from those three conditions, the timing belt doesn't know or care how much power the engine is making. So there's no need for a stronger timing belt if you mod the engine for higher power. Motive power is transmitted out the crankshaft to the trans to the wheels, but does not pass through the timing belt at all.

Comment: @MTA - Well said.